# Shared clipboard and drag and drop not working on Windows 10 Guest with Ubuntu Host 20.04

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and on top of it I installed Virtualbox. I installed Windows as the guest OS, and enabled bidirectional option for shared clipboard and drag and drop. But it does not work. I have googled the solution but only see solutions for when Ubuntu is the guest.

What should I do to enable this feature?